# Upload and read dataset SAS - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sas, odbc

I am uploading a dataset to MS SQL server, and I did it in two ways

```
first one: 

proc sql; 
create table lib.dataset as 
select ID, date_reg from havingdata
;
Quit;
```

Here date format is YYMMDD10.

All went well, and date format also looks good on SQL server. However When i access the same from SAS, the date format changes to Date9.

```
2.I created the table directly on SQL server  

create table dbo.dataset
 (
ID char(11) NOT NULL, 
date_reg date,
);
```

And then inserted the values from SAS

```
proc sql; 
insert into lib.dataset
select ID, date_reg from havingdata
;
quit;
```

all went well, but again the same problem when I access the data from SAS, the date format changes from YYMMDD10. to Date9,

How can I get the same format as of in the SQL Server.

the libname I use is

```
libname lib odbc noprompt="dsn=myserver; database=dab" schema=dbo 
bulkload=yes;
```

Comment: Why does it matter? Formats only control appearances, it doesn't change the usage in any manner.

Comment: you are right.. it doesn't matter much. just wanted to know if there is a way for this.

Comment: But is there a way?

Comment: AFAIK, no there is no way. SAS does automatic assumptions when hitting a SQL data base.